# MA process formula explained

Tags: time-series, arima, moving-average

I'm currently reading about moving average processes. According to my textbook, the following applies:

$$y_t=\mu + \epsilon_t -\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}-...-\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q}$$

---

Questions on formula:

-Does this presuppose a constant process, since we only have $\mu$ and error terms in the formula?

-Is this in any way related to the simple moving average ($M_T=\frac {y_T + y_{T-1}+...+y_{T-N+1}}{N}$)?

-Why do we *subtract* the weighted values, instead of adding everything up and dividing with the number of time points (as shown above)?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "constant process"? Stationary process, maybe. In which case this is correct: the marginal distribution of $y_t$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: 3. Adding or subtracting $\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}+...+\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q}$ does not make much of a difference since the distribution of the $\epsilon_t$'s is symmetric around zero.

Comment: 2. If you replace $y_t$ with $M_t$, $\epsilon_t$ with $y_t-\mathbb{E}[Y_t]$, $\mu$ with $\mathbb{E}[Y_t]$, and all $\theta_i$'s with $1/N$, the moving average is indeed a special case of an MA process.

Comment: With constant process I mean something like $y_t=\beta_0 + u_t$, so that there's no trend (not like say: $y_t=\beta_0 +\beta_1t + u_t$)

Comment: And what information do we gain from subtracting (or adding, for that matter) those weighted error terms?

Why is this useful?

Comment: The weighted and lagged error terms are there to create correlation between the $y_t$'s. Up to lag $q$.

Comment: Are the values of the $\theta$s constant/constantly decreasing or are they totally arbitrary?

Comment: I definitely suggest you to read an introductory book on times series, like [Brockwell and Davis' Introduction to Times Series and Forecasting](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0387953515/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0387953515&linkCode=as2&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkId=PTRZV7XJJ3KBFL47). Or an equivalent on-line introduction. Like [Davis' notes](www.stat.columbia.edu/~rdavis/lectures/Session6.pdf).

Comment: That's my course book, I'm asking since these things weren't specified, at least not in chapters 4, 5 or 7, the ones I'm supposed to read.

Comment: If we are talking of the same edition, I would suggest you (re)read Chapter 2 on stationarity and Chapter 3 on ARMA models. This would answer most of your earlier questions. Chapter 5 is about inference on such models.

Comment: On closer inspection, my course book (though sharing the same name) is written by Montgomery/Jennings/Kulachi. I'll try a peek at the ones you suggested.

Comment: The subtraction is simply a matter of convention that goes back to the book by Box and Jenkins.